# simple EJB jar deployed in jboss with its own log4j configuration

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, ejb

I have a simple EJB jar with a stateless session bean, deployed in JBOSS AS 4.2.2, under `<JBOSS_HOME>/server/default/deploy`. The bean is registered under JNDI tree as viewed from jboss jmx console and I am able to access it through a remote java client outside JBOSS.

Inside EJB jar, I have added some logging to be written to a separate log file, using apache log4j jar and log4j.xml. But I am not able to view any of the logs.

Also I do not wish to use jboss-log4j.xml, since there will be many other EJBs to be deployed and wish to have separate log4j for each EJB application.

Here is my one of the EJB-jar contents:

EJB_DS.jar:
log4j.xml
classes

apache log4j jar is added to `<JBOSS_HOME>/server/default/lib` path.

Kindly highlight if i have missed any points for enabling log4j configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an option in JBoss, unfortunately. The entire server operates off a single log4j configuration (specified by `conf/jboss-log4j.xml`), and your EJBs cannot change that. It's not ideal, but that's the way it is.

Also, you don't need to add `log4j.jar` to `server/default/lib`, JBoss already has its own internal copy.

Comment: ok ..i thought there will be a way override default jboss log4j. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @user309281: You could experiment with a non-log4j solution inside the EJB, such as sfl4j+logback. If you do it right, this should not interfere with log4j, allowing you to do what you want.